# Slow android SQL inserts

Tags: android, sqlite

I read a lot of articles / questions on SQL insertion on android.

I'm using what I think to be the most up-to-date way to do it :

My DB Table is simple : `CREATE TABLE shapes ( shape_id INTEGER, shape_pt_lat REAL, shape_pt_lon REAL)`

But it consists of 120 000 entries.

I insert them from parsing a CSV file.

- I compiled a SqlStatement
- I parse a bulk of lines from the CSV (5000)
- I initialize a transaction (db.beginTransaction())
- for each line of my bulk : I bind data to the statement with the `sqlStatement.bindXXX methods`
- then `sqlStatement.executeInsert();`
- then `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` and `db.endTransaction();`
- I perform another bulk of 5000 lines of the csv files again ...

I just bought a Moto G, and when I launch it via Eclipse (with or without debbugging) it takes more than one minute to load all the 120 000 lines.
This seems suspsect but I don't see what is wrong, since I used the approach described in a lot of SO answers.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I see a lot of "GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 27% free 12632K/17248K, paused 33ms, total 33ms" log in LogCat when the code is executing

Comment: It might not be the insertion operation that is costing you, but the CSV parsing. Still, 1 minute for 120000 entries seems normal to me. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: ... wouldn't it be much better if you provided a pre-filled database?

Comment: that's what I'm thinking about. I tried to build the SQL database using Firefox extension (SQLite Manager) but I had some problems plugging it into my app. I will retry, following "how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database" Stack overflow question . The only drawback of that solution is that you have to ship the app with the database in the assets directory, which requires additional space. And the other problem is that the database content is updated every week by a third-party online service, so I will have to update the DB from the web anyway.